# Can't compile a c++ file using OpenGL library on Mac OS using Xcode and Terminal

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, opengl

I am trying to compile this [simple program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYYLi.png).

But every time I try to do it using Xcode or the terminal I get these [warnings and errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpQh0.png).

Comment: what's a "g++ file"?

Comment: also, what about entering image descriptions?

Comment: also, removed the "kthxbai!" closing phrase; don't worry, we don't mind, but they are deprecated on SO, because *everyone* is asking for help, so saying "hope you can help me" is really redundant.

Comment: Also, you should *not* include screenshots of text in your question. Why on earth aren't you copy & pasting the source code text, and then format it with the "format as code" button??

Answer (score 2):

First of all, what is a "g++" file supposed to mean?

- g++ is a command invoking a GNU c++ compiler.
- c++ compilers are there to compile c++ code.
- OpenGL is a plain-C API, and so is your code.
- c++ compilers are not meant for compiling c code, although they can (with some "buts")

Try out and figure the following in function `display()`:

- why is the line `glClear(GL_POLYGON)` *wrong* ?

First three line of `display()` should be of the following syntax:

```
//glClear(GL_POLYGON);  //this is meaningless !
glClearColor(0.,0.,0., 1.);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);   
glColor4f(.1,.2,.3, 1.);
```

If you compile it in Linux you must link at least `libGL`, in OSX the corresponding framework: `-framework opengl`, in Windows you must link `opengl32`

In addition to OpenGL your program also depends on GLUT, so you have to link to that as well.

Deprecated doesn't mean *retired*.

Enjoy learning OpenGL!

Comment: Thanks for your edit and taking your time, @datenwolf (-:

Comment: Ok sorry for the issues involving my question, I am not very used to programming but I am trying to learn OpenGL for a project.

Comment: But the thing is what I should do to successfully correct the mistakes in the program? I mean I just can't see any mistakes on it. I am using sublime and trying to execute on the terminal

#include <glut/glut.h>
void display()
{
    glClear(GL_POLYGON);
    
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    glVertex2f(-0.5,-0.5);
    glVertex2f(-0.5,0.5);
    glVertex2f(0.5,0.5);
    glVertex2f(0.5,-0.5);
    glEnd();
    
    glFlush();
    
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutCreateWindow("simple");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMainLoop();
}

Comment: 1. Delete `glClear(GL_POLYGON);`. 2. Copy-paste the three lines I wrote in the place where `glClear(GL_POLYGON);` used to be, just before `glBegin(GL_POLYGON);`. Hope this is clear enough now.